# Node JS app with https via IIS reverse proxy

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, rewrite, node.js

Could you help me with https via IIS reverse proxy?
I set up my nodejs app in local network as http://mayapp.domain.com:8080 and https://myapp.domain.com:8443. It works Ok.
For external access i use IIS reverse proxy (ARR and URL Rewrite module 3.0) with port forwarding (8080->80, 8443->443).
External http works ok now, but https returns 404 (Not found)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpplatformhandler/info HttpPlatformHandler offers better integration.

Answer (score 0):

I found a answer.
I add https binding for myapp.domain.com in "default web site" on proxy server